# Button function in cshtml

Tags: sql, razor

I have this button code

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="approvebutton" name="button">Approve</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="rejectbutton" name="button">Reject</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="@row.appointment_id" name="hiddenbutton" style="display: none"></button>
```

And the code to fetch it is

```
if(IsPost){
    var appointment_id = Request.Form["hiddenbutton"];

    if(Request.Form["button"] == "approvebutton"){
        //approve the appointment
        var approveappointmentcommand = "UPDATE appointment set appointment_approve = 1 WHERE appointment_id = @0";//1 for approved        
        var approveappointmentdata = db.Execute(approveappointmentcommand, appointment_id);
    }

    if(Request.Form["button"] == "rejectbutton"){
        //reject the appointment
        var rejectappointmentcommand = "DELETE FROM appointment WHERE appointment_id = @0";
        var rejectappointmentdata = db.Execute(rejectappointmentcommand, appointment_id);
    }
}
```

I want the deletion/approval to work against the specific id of the items. But actually nothing really happens. I mean no query gets executed.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is your hidden button; replace it with an hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenbutton" value="@row.appointment_id" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="approvebutton" name="button">Approve</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="rejectbutton" name="button">Reject</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="@row.appointment_id" name="hiddenbutton" style="display: none"></button>
```

when you submit the form the request data will look like this

```
hiddenbutton={row.appointment_id}&button=approve&button=reject
```

and

```
Request.Form["hiddenbutton"] = {row.appointment_id}
Request.Form["button"] = "approve,reject"
```

without using javascript

you will need 2 forms or 1 radio button